# RewriteRule versus Redirect - which is better?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

### Intro

For a very very long time I have used `RewriteRule` as redirection command. For example I used this:

```apache
RewriteRule ^some-page.html$ /new-page.html [R=301,L]
```

But recently I've found other method, using `Redirect` keyword:

```apache
Redirect 301 /some-page.html /new-page.html
```

### Question

Which method is better and should be used as primary tool?

Better is considered by being:

- more stable
- safer
- faster
- more acknowledged by 'community'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @anubhava, `RewriteRule` is far more powerful and more useful as a general tool. However, to answer your specific "better" criteria:

> more stable

Nothing in it. `Redirect` (mod_alias) has been around longer. (?)

> safer

Again, if you know what you're doing then one isn't any "safer" than the other. `RewriteRule` is more complex so there is more room for error. One thing you should be wary of, however, is that you should never use `Redirect` (mod_alias) and `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) together in the same file. They belong to different modules and execute at different times. Using them together can produce unexpected results.

> faster

Some would argue that `Redirect` is faster. It is a lot simpler.

> more acknowledged by 'community'

Debatable. `RewriteRule` would seem to be used more these days, but it does a lot more. And many will use it because that is what they always use. The Apache docs do recommend that if you are just doing a simple redirect then a mod_alias `Redirect` is preferred:

[When not to use mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/avoid.html)

You should note that the two directives you posted above are not exactly the same. `Redirect` is prefix matching and anything after the match is automatically passed to the target URL. Whereas in your `RewriteRule` you have used anchors to explicitly mark the start and end of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it pretty much explain everything :)

Answer (score 3):

Beyond any doubt `RewriteRule` will serve you better as it has regex support and has many more goodies available in `mod_rewrite` module. Other one is older `mod_alias` module and has no support for many important things like:

1. No `RewriteCond` for example matching query string
2. No internal rewrite
3. No support of env variables
4. No way to use proxy
5. No support of flags such as `NE`, `NC`, `QSA` etc.

List will be pretty long but all said and done you can rely on `mod_rewrite` to serve you better.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Didn't know that it's from `mod_alias` (never heard of this module before).

Comment: About the regex: there is also regex support with RedirectMatch, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: I know that but comparison is with `Redirect` not `RedirectMatch`